# Eclipse Plugin-how to remove recently opened file names being displayed in file menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on eclipse editor which display content from remote location. And once it is closed the remote file is deleted and it is only created only when we read it next time but with some other name.

Thus I intend to remove recently opened files names from file menu in eclipse.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent files list works by retaining a list of `IEditorInput` objects used the editors.

Each time the list is refreshed `IEditorInput.exists()` is called to check that the input still exists.

So it should just be a matter of making your `IEditorInput` behave as expected.

The Eclipse source for this is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorHistory`, `org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorHistoryItem`, `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ReopenEditorMenu`.